# How to submit PySpark job on Kubernetes (minikube) using spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, kubernetes, pyspark

I have a PySpark job present locally on my laptop. If I want to submit it on my minikube cluster using spark-submit, any idea how to pass the python file ?

I'm using following command, but it isn't working

```
./spark-submit \
        --master k8s://https://192.168.64.6:8443 \
        --deploy-mode cluster \
        --name amazon-data-review \
        --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=jupyter \
        --conf spark.executor.instances=1 \
        --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.limit.cores=1 \
        --conf spark.executor.cores=1 \
        --conf spark.executor.memory=500m \
        --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=prateek/spark-ubuntu-2.4.5 \
        --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
        --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Always \
        --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullSecrets=dockerlogin \
        --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true \
        --conf spark.eventLog.dir=s3a://prateek/spark-hs/ \
        --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=xxxxx \
        --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=xxxxx \
        --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem \
        --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload=true \
        /Users/prateek/apache-spark/amazon_data_review.py
```

Getting following error -

```
python3: can't open file '/Users/prateek/apache-spark/amazon_data_review.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Is it required to keep the file within the Docker image itself. Can't we run it locally by keeping it on laptop

Answer (score 4):

Spark on Kubernetes doesn't support submitting locally stored files with `spark-submit`.

What you could do to make it work in cluster mode is to build Spark Docker image based on `prateek/spark-ubuntu-2.4.5` with `amazon_data_review.py` put inside of it (eg using Docker `COPY /Users/prateek/apache-spark/amazon_data_review.py /amazon_data_review.py` statement).

Then just refer to it in the `spark-submit` command using `local://` file system, eg.:

```sh
spark-submit \
  --master ... \
  --conf ... \
  ...
  local:///amazon_data_review.py
```

The alternative is to store that file on `http(s)://` or `hdfs://`-like accessible location.

Comment: Has this changed at all with recent versions? What would be the recommended way now? Thanks!

Comment: Very good question. By checking the docs in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#dependency-management I see that now you can provide the config `spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path=s3a://<s3-bucket>/path` (which should not necessary point to S3 but any hdfs-compatible location) and use local FS path to the job artifact (eg. `file:///full/path/to/app.jar`). Then, if the hdfs location access credentials are set, `the app jar file will be uploaded to the S3 and then when the driver is launched it will be downloaded to the driver pod and will be added to its classpath`.

Answer (score -1):

It's solved. Running it with client mode helped to run it

--deploy-mode client